# Is there a service that can help me if I lose everything overseas?

Tags: international-travel

By everything I mean losing

- Passport and IDs
- Bank cards
- Cash
- Phone and other devices
- SIMs

In a country where your home country has no representation (no consulate, embassy) and you don't speak the local language and locals don't speak a language you know.

I have my own plan for this scenario but looking for easier alternatives

Comment: This is a bit extreme, but higher-end credit cards (especially Amex) and some travel insurance providers have pretty extensive assistance services. Of course you need a way to get in touch with them. Otherwise your best bet is probably to get to the local police and get in touch with your nearest consulate.

Comment: Any suggested travel insurance companies?

Comment: Haven’t personably used them, and whatever experience I have heard about dates back quite a very long while, but Europ Assistance was at some point the reference. Not sure what the situation is nowadays. Of course if you really go to very remote places in very difficult circumstances you may need very specialised support providers.

Comment: "locals don't speak a language you know" sounds like an artificial constraint more than a real question. What does that mean? Nobody in the country speaks any language you know? You're writing this in English, can you name any country on earth where nobody speaks any English? How are you going to contact your service of choice?

Comment: Found the software engineer :) It means 1 in 200+ speaks a language you know when you go outside and try to talk o people

Comment: Why don't you state your own plan? Otherwise someone runs the risk of spending a lot of time researching something you've already thought of. This seems to be more of an intellectual exercise or trolling than a genuine request anyway, and this is grounds for deletion, so you should try and prove this is a genuine question.

Answer (score 6):

- If the lost documents involve your ID, **you need to talk to the local police.** Usually they will have procedures in place for a foreigner who does not speak their local language. It might take some time to get the right translator, but since you speak English, it should not be too long.
- If you are an EU citizen, your can go to another EU embassy. There are agreements to cover for each other if there is no embassy of your state.
- Your state may have a [honorary consul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consul_(representative)#Honorary_consul) near you. These people have fewer rights and duties than a career diplomat, but they can put you in touch with authorities.

Comment: correct. And the local police will know to contact a consulate or embassy to help out, especially if they don't have their own translator services on call (and will certainly know how to get you there if needed too).

Comment: I remember someone spending a night in jail in russia because they went to the police without ID. But when you lose everything and unable to reach anyone who can help, I guess there would be no other option than to trust corrupt cops?

Comment: @oooooo, I believe most Western governments warn their citizens against travel to Russia, in part because of arbitrary detention.

Comment: I think this was before the sanctions

Comment: If authorities in any country are suspicious (e.g. of your immigration status), they may detain you until your identity has been verified. Whether this is better than sleeping in the street and begging for food is up to you.

Answer (score 5):

In countries without direct representation, other countries will offer limited consulate support.

For example: in Iran, Switzerland will have limited consulate services for US citizens or Canada will use its embassy in Turkey for consular services in Iran (Turkey will act as a proxy in Iran).

It's probably the same for other countries (Germany, France, UK, ...)

That is why you should register with the closest national embassy and maybe those consulates before going to those countries.

If you travel in "unsafe" countries you can have specialized insurances and extraction/evacuation services with global phone numbers and they probably all have local resources (I think Global Rescue is one of them).

Obviously this is all legal. It's not a covert extraction and is mostly used in case of medical emergency situations. These services are mostly designed for corporate use with expats working in other countries and are used in crisis situations.

Also, if you're in a bigger city, there are always major chains' hotels that cater more to international travelers where you could walk in; works well if you're a white guy in a non white country.

I assume there are other tips or tricks if you're really screwed and you loose everything in the middle of the jungle in Thailand (for example).

Comment: France and Germany simply have an embassy in Iran. France's foreign ministry only issued a formal “do not travel” advice at the beginning of 2020.

Comment: Can you elaborate this part? "That is why you should register with the closest national embassy and maybe those consulate before going to those countries" how do you register? What's the point of registering?

Comment: How you register depends on your country. My country for example offers a website, where every citizen can register themselves, if they travel abroad. Reasons for registering would be, so that the local embassies have a record of you, should an emergency happen in that country (e.g. natural disaster, wars etc.).

Comment: @dunni So it is useless then? Governments are corporations. They are not incentivized to help you especially during natural disasters and wars.

Comment: It's probably useless in some circumstances, but useful in other. It being (part of) their job to help citizens of their country is in most cases enough of an incentive.